# What is the proper Cakephp Model Naming Conventions

Tags: php, cakephp, naming-conventions, models

Table is "rate_chapters"

Model file name is "rateChapter"

Model class name is "rateChapter"
class RateChapter extends AppModel{
}//file name is rate_chapter.php

WHen I query this model I get a error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class

// in controller

$this->rate_chapter->find('all');

DOnt' understand naming convention. Read it, but not clear..

Comment: thats not enough,show your code

Answer (score 1):

Table: **rate_chapters**

Model: **RateChapter**

```
 $this->RateChapter->find("all");
```

ModelFile: **RateChapter.php**

Controller file: **RateChaptersController.php**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was $this->RateChapter->find('all');

Comment: But I'm afraid your not using the CakePHP naming conventions. The file name of you model must be RateChapter.php refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the naming conventions at:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

As you found out Models are always singular (tables are plural).